# Cannot implicitely convert type WebApplication1.models.Table1 to int

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, get

I want to use sql query in a get api as:

```
[Route("empLevel/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetEmpHierarchy(int id)
{
    List<Employee> emp = entity.Employees.ToList();
    List<Employee> mngr = entity.Employees.ToList();

    var query = (from e in emp
                 join m in mngr on e.MngId equals m.Id into tab1
                 from mngrN in tab1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new Employee { Id = e, MngId = m}).ToList();
    return Ok(query);
}
```

But I am getting an error on the line `ID = e` where it is saying that `e` cannot be converted to int.

In my models class I have:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Grade { get; set; }
    public int? MngId { get; set; }
    public virtual SalarySplit GradeNavigation { get; set; }        
}
```

Please give a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `e` represents an object of type `Employee`. You are trying to assign whole object into the property `Id`. Instead you should use the value in property of that `e` object.

```
var query = (from e in emp
             join m in mngr on e.MngId equals m.Id into tab1
             from mngrN in tab1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new Employee { Id = e.Id, MngId = m.Id}).ToList();
```

---

**Bonus:** If I'm not mistaken, the filtering won't be applied there and you get either object with or without manager (both). In that case the query can be simplified:

```
var query = (from e in emp
             select new Employee { Id = e.Id, MngId = e.MngId}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because e is a sort of an object and your ID is an int.
so you probably want something like this.

```
select new Employee { Id = e.MngId, MngId =  m.Id}).ToList();
```